# LIST ASSIGNMENT ERROR

Tags: python, list, random

I am trying to assign strings to a list "a" based on the value generated randomly.
but when I run the code, I get this error:

a[i]="INT"
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

```
import random

a= list()

for i in range(35):
b=random.randint(0,1)
    if b==0:

         a[i]="Internet"
    else:
        a[i]="Library"


print(a[5])


fout=open("/Users/BATTLEDRUM/Desktop/review.txt","w")

for i in range(len(a)):

fout.write(a[i]+"\n")



print(a.count("Library"))
```

What am I doing wrong?

FYI I tried using a.append(), but that gives me fewer items than 35, adn I want 35 items in a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `list` is empty; it has no slots to fill, and you can't assign to indices that don't exist yet. If the goal is to add elements to the end of a `list` (it looks like it), you use `list.append`:

```
for i in range(35):
    b=random.randint(0,1)
    if b==0:
        a.append("Internet")
    else:
        a.append("Library")
```

Side-note: `for i in range(len(someseq)):` is almost always "wrong", and in this case, there is a much better, faster, and more Pythonic version (also using `with` to close the file properly and predictably), where you just iterate the sequence directly, instead of calculating and looking up indices like you would in C; in C, there is no real difference, but in Python, creating and using the indices is much slower (and unnecessarily complicated) than just iterating directly:

```
with open("/Users/BATTLEDRUM/Desktop/review.txt","w") as fout:
    for x in a:
        fout.write(x+"\n")
```

Comment: I tried that, but that gives me a fewer items than 35. I want 35 items in a

Comment: @BattleDrum: As written in my version (your version is riddled with indentation errors, and I could easily see your `else` case being attached to the `for` loop by accident, not the `if` block), it is guaranteed to have 35 elements. One possible issue though is that your code is at global scope, and never closes the file handle; depending on the version of Python, that could mean buffered writes never get written to the file (using the file via a `with` statement as I demonstrated would fix that on all versions of Python).

Comment: @BattleDrum: How do you know you only got 35 items? Did you count the lines in the output? The code as written never directly `print`s the number of items (`print(len(a))` would let you know for sure).

Comment: I used len(). I now closed the file and it worked. It must have been that.

Comment: @BattleDrum: Excellent. Good to know my pedantic nitpicking solves real problems. :-) As a rule, if you can use an object with `with`, you should; this applies to file-like objects, locks, database and network connections, etc. It frees you from remembering to release the reserved resource, and protects you against exceptions bypassing explicit calls to the resource release method (`close`, `release`, `commit`, `rollback`, whatever). Use it religiously.